# How to find merge commits in history done using "git merge -s ours" option?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Misusing the "-s ours" merge option when merging origin/develop into local develop essentially throws away work done since the last time develop was updated. I've manually found two instances of this in the git history by deliberately looking through the history for files I know have went missing.

**Is there a way to find all commits that were done using the "-s ours" merge option?**

I imagine it's possible by comparing merge commits with their parents and checking if only one parents branches contents were actually taken but I've got no idea how to translate this theory into a git command. What command do I even start with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR (but untested)

As a shell script:

```
git rev-list --merges HEAD |
while read rev; do
    thistree=$(git rev-parse $rev^{tree})
    p1tree=$(git rev-parse $rev^1^{tree})
    if [ $thistree = $p1tree ]; then
        echo "commit $rev has the effect of -s ours"
    fi
done
```

#### Long

The immediate answer is "no" (but read on).  The *actual strategy used* is not recorded automatically.  (If the individuals doing all the merges were very self-disciplined, perhaps they recorded that information in every merge-commit message.  Based on your problem description, this clearly didn't happen....)  But that's not necessarily the interesting problem anyway.  It's possible for someone to create a merge that has the *effect* of `-s ours` without actually using the `ours` strategy.

The more interesting question is automatically finding merges that have the *effect* of `-s ours`, whether or not the option was used; and that *is* easily automated.

The problem reduces to:

- Find merge commits: the tool for this is `git rev-list`.
- Test merge commits to see if they had the effect of `-s ours`: the tool for this is ... well, see below; there are several possibilities.

Finding merge commits is trivial once you know how `git rev-list` enumerates commits.  Like `git log`, you give `git rev-list` a starting point, and Git then works *backwards* from that point, through history that is reachable from that commit, until it runs out of history or runs into a commit you've told it to use as a stopping point.

Typically, a good starting point is `HEAD`, which is the commit you have checked out right now, which is probably the tip commit of a branch.  You can even give multiple starting points, such as `--branches` (every tip of every branch) or `--all` (every commit with a label, whether that label is a branch name, a tag name, a remote-tracking name, or even one of the special names like `refs/stash` for the stash).

You then want to restrict the output to listing only merge commits.  A merge commit is any commit with at least two parents: `--min-parents=2`.  There's a synonym for this that you might prefer, though, so we get, e.g.:

```
git rev-list --merges HEAD
```

to start from where you are now and work backwards through all commits reachable from `HEAD`.  (For more on this *reachability* concept, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)

The output from `git rev-list` is a stream of commit hash IDs that meet the `rev-list` criteria, in this case, `--merges` (every reachable merge commit): not very useful to humans, but great for computer programs.  Now we just need to write the program that identifies the *interesting* merges.

We already saw that a merge commit is a commit with at least two parents.  What `-s ours` or equivalent does is tell Git that the new merge commit's snapshot (its stored tree) should match one of the two parents, specifically the *first* parent.  You might want to relax your conditions and check whether the tree matches that of the second parent (a `theirs`-strategy merge, except that there's no built in `-s theirs`), or for octopus merges, *any* of the parents, but "matches first parent" will probably do, and is slightly easier.

The two obvious ways to do this are:

- Compare the merge commit's tree with its first parent's tree: `git diff` (or its plumbing equivalent) with the two specific commits or tree hashes.
- Or, since we only care about the entire tree, just compare the top level tree hash directly.  This checks for a pure exact match; using a full `git diff` or equivalent would allow you to relax the match criteria a bit if necessary.

We'll code the second one—comparing the stored `tree` hash in the merge and in its first parent—in shell-script since it's perhaps faster and in any case demonstrates more of the various Git tools.  We start with the generic "read every commit hash" loop:

```
while read rev; do ...; done
```

Each revision will be available within the loop as `$rev`.

Now we simply turn `$rev` (a commit) into its own tree:

```
git rev-parse $rev^{tree}
```

which uses [the gitrevisions syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) to find the specified commit's tree hash ID.  We must save that in a variable:

```
thistree=$(git rev-parse $rev^{tree})
```

We then want to find the first parent's tree.  The first parent is, in gitrevisions syntax, `${rev}^1`.  The braces here are technically unnecessary so I'll omit them.  Then we want that commit's tree, which we need to save in another variable:

```
p1tree=$(git rev-parse $rev^1^{tree})
```

If the two trees match, the commit `$rev` has the *effect* of `-s ours`, whether or not it was made with `-s ours`, so we should print its hash ID, or even run `git show` on it.

The final version of this loop (putting all the parts together) is the one at the top of this answer.